# JQGrid version >= 4.3.2 new events for cascading dropdown?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-4, cascadingdropdown

I'm working with ASP.NET 4.0 MVC 4 and I'm tasked with creating a data bound JQGrid with cascading dropdown selects on each record.  I see several examples of this out there but none with the current version of JQGrid 4.4.0, and I can't get the existing examples to work.  There was a [whole new set of events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2) released in 4.3.2 but they're not very well documented yet as far as I can tell.

None of my dataEvents are working even when I just use an alert stub.  I also see there's a JQuery Cell Edit module that might be able to help but it's awfully buggy.

I've been trying for several hours to scour the web and decided to finally ask for an updated example here.  The latest I've found is the ever popular http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditWithDependendSelects.htm, which uses version 4.1.1.

Thanks

Comment: `and I can't get the existing examples to work.` -> and [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Tried the example above using dataEvents with type: 'change'.  Also tried the jqGridAfterEditCell event listed in JQGrid's wiki.  Can't get either event to fire.

Comment: It doesn't help that version 4.3.2 introduced a whole new set of events and they're not very well documented.  That seems like a more major change for such a minor release version.
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2